# Can the next developer survey include an optional Meyers Briggs question?

Tags: feature-request, survey

I know that MB, and all personality inventories, can be made controversial.  Regardless, the psychological and psychiatric fields utilize MB data in the scope of working with people.

It could be very interesting to see what Meyers Briggs types are typical to the SO developer community.

---

In reading related material, I see [here are the Big5 problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits#Critique), and [here are MBTI problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator#Criticism). There's no holier-than-thou ground between them. In my [reading of other models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Personality_typologies) there doesn't seem to be one that is absent of criticisms.  Meyers Briggs also seems to be the most well-known.  I'm not suggesting we ask people for the moon sign or something....

Comment: It's not just "controversial". It's (AFAIK) about as reliable as zodiac signs. It cannot and should not serve as a way to classify things. Some people using it is a poor argument - some people make hiring decisions based on astrology or numerology, too but I wouldn't want these in the developer survey, either.

Answer (score 17):

If you're going to do this, Myers-Briggs Type Indicators are a particularly poor choice:

- There is no scientific evidence that they measure what they purport to measure, except for the introversion/extraversion axis (even there, it's not clear that MBTI is the "best" way to measure it).
- There is no evidence that it correlates with or predicts anything useful, particularly career path, academic performance, or even *itself* (when you retest people).
- It purports to break everyone into a mere 16 categories, which is far too few, and it also draws the lines down the middle of the bell curves, so that the ambiverts are quite arbitrarily divided into "slightly extraverted" and "slightly introverted" groups, and are then lumped in with all of the extreme extraverts and introverts respectively. This is bad because most people are ambiverts to some extent.
- As an introvert, I always found the P/J distinction needlessly confusing and complicated.

If we want a personality test at all, we should use something scientifically grounded, like the [Big Five system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits). I'm not sure that's a Good Idea either, but at least it would not suffer from the above problems (for the most part).

Comment: Though all of that is great, the reality is that a broad number of people have taken an MB survey at some point, and do not consider it very controversial. It would be a way to get some form of data, as opposed to none.  Especially considering that even the public wiki critiques of Big-5 are more damning that your summary

Comment: No, they certainly are not. Go read the MBTI wiki article. It's explicitly described as pseudoscience.

Comment: Just so we dont' have to be quarreling in comments on Meta: [here are the Big5 problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits#Critique), and [here are MBTI problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator#Criticism).  There's no holier-than-thou ground here